# How do I sort and match in columns with similar data in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, sorting

I have data in separate columns which I wish to match up. An example:

```
UL Application: Outdoor Volts: 120-277  Watts: 14   
UL Application: Post    Volts: 120-277  Watts: 14   
UL Application: Outdoor Volts: 120-277  Watts: 24   
UL Application: Outdoor Volts: 120-277  Watts: 24   

Photocell: No Photocell Safety Listing: cETLus - Wet    Volts: 120-277  Watts: 11
Photocell: No Photocell Safety Listing: cETLus - Wet    Volts: 120-277  Watts: 20
Photocell: No Photocell Safety Listing: cETLus - Wet    Volts: 120-277  Watts: 38
Photocell: No Photocell Safety Listing: cETLus - Wet    Volts: 120-277  Watts: 32
Photocell: No Photocell Safety Listing: cETLus - Wet    Volts: 120-277  Watts: 20
Safety Listing: cETLus - Wet    UL Application: Outdoor Watts: 20   
Photocell: No Photocell Safety Listing: cETLus - Wet    Volts: 120-277  Watts: 30
Safety Listing: cETLus - Wet    UL Application: Outdoor Volts: 120  Watts: 30
UL Application: Outdoor Volts: 120-277  Watts: 14   
UL Application: Outdoor Volts: 120-277  Watts: 14   
UL Application: Outdoor Volts: 120-277  Watts: 24   
UL Application: Outdoor Volts: 120-277  Watts: 24
```

I want to have all the cells with "`Watts:`" in their value line up in the same column, all matching "`Volts:`" align etc.

Is there a way to do this within Notepad++?

Comment: @Lightbulb, can you check the question we've linked and confirm whether or not that answers your question? I can see that it might, but there's a chance it doesn't. If it doesn't can you clarify how your question differs?

Comment: Hi. No the code alignment plugin is not the solution.  I was looking to have columns of data be sorted by a possible set of characters.  For example, there may be attributes that start with "Lumens:" or "CRI:", but in different columns.  I'd like to be able to these attributes sorted so that all cells with "Lumens" is in one column, all "CRI" in another, etc.